# How to retrieve SubItem.Text property from listview item

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am trying to retrieve ListView SubItem `.Text` property.

My ListView has two columns: ID and name. I want to access name for specific ID and store it in variable:

```
string nameValue = listView1.Items[0].SubItems[0].Text;
```

The above code should look at first item (index zero) at my listview and then get the first subitem's text. Sadly it takes the `Item.Text` instead of `SubItem.Text` so it stores "ID" column value instead of "Name" column value.

Where do I make the mistake? I have tried with different SubItems index values (getting obvious "OurOfRange exceptions or trying something like `SubItems.Item[0]` over `SubItems[0]` but it does not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah yes, I remember this catching me out the first time!

The `SubItems` array actually contains all the elements which includes in index [0] the Text.

So you simply need to increment the sub-index by 1 to get the value you expect.  You should ideally also add a null check just to be sure and avoid exceptions.

```
string nameValue = listView1.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text;
```